# Whenever I click submit button on a infopath form I created, the subject and attachment name come back as NaN

Tags: sharepoint, infopath, sharepoint-designer, nan

I am trying to create a form that submits to email addresses but with unique subjects and attachments each time.

To do this, I put a formula in as a rule for a submit button for the user to click. The formula I used is supposed to create a unique subject and attachment name in the email that gets sent out.

The fields I used are subjectList and wikiEntryTitle. They are both drop down lists and when I click to submit the form, the email that arrives has NaN as the subject and NaN as the attachment name.

"[" + subjectList + "] - " + wikiEntryTitle

Is there something small that I am missing?

Thanks ahead of time.

Answer (score 0):

on button submit rules, set first the value of the subjectList and wikieEntryTitle before the "SharePoint Submit" rule.

It may be that you submitting it first before setting those values.